# How to insert data in movie genre relation table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a IMDb data file with information about movies and I want to create a database.
I created two tables: movie and genre

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie(
            budget integer,
            homepage text,
            id integer,
            original_language text,
            original_title text,
            overview text,
            popularity integer,
            release_date text,
            revenue integer,
            runtime integer,
            status text,
            tagline text,
            title text,
            vote_average integer,
            vote_count integer,
            primary key(id)
)""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE genre(
            id integer,
            name text,
            primary key(id)
)""")
```

Then I inserted data into the tables like this:

```
for index, movies in data.iterrows():
    try:
      c.execute("INSERT INTO movie VALUES (:budget, :homepage, :id, :original_language, :original_title, :overview, :popularity, :release_date, :revenue, :runtime, :status, :tagline, :title, :vote_average, :vote_count)", 
                {'budget': movies['budget'], 'homepage': movies['homepage'], 'id': movies['id'], 'original_language': movies['original_language'], 'original_title': movies['original_title'], 
                 'overview': movies['overview'], 'popularity': movies['popularity'], 'release_date': movies['release_date'], 'revenue': movies['revenue'], 'runtime': movies['runtime'], 
                 'status': movies['status'], 'tagline': movies['tagline'],
                 'title': movies['title'], 'vote_average': movies['vote_average'], 'vote_count': movies['vote_count']})
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
      pass # ignore SQLite complaints about UNIQUE primary keys


for movie_genres in data['genres']:
    for genres in movie_genres:
      try:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO genre VALUES (:id, :name)", {'id': genres['id'], 'name': genres['name']})
      except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        pass # ignore SQLite complaints about UNIQUE primary keys
```

Movie and genre have a many to many relationship, and I want to create a table for this and also insert data in this table.

How do I do this??

Comment: Create a new table with having movie_id and genre_id as foreign key.Then you can add the data.If you can show us the sample data then it would be helpful

Comment: I created:
```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie_genres(
            mid integer,
            gid integer,
            primary key(mid, gid)
            foreign key(mid) references movie(id)
            foreign key(gid) references genre(id)
)""")
```
But then I don't know how to insert the data.. What sample data do you mean? The data should be obtained from the datafile, same way as genre and movie data was inserted...

Comment: can you please insert the sample data in the tables and then show the data?

Comment: I mean insert the sample data in movie and genre tables

Comment: I'm sorry im not sure what you mean.. The datafile contains information on 5000 movies.
So for example:
budget = 237000000
homepage = http://www.avatarmovie.com/
id = 19995
original_language = En
etc etc..

for genre:
id = 3
name = Action

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to insert into the table

```
insert into movie_genres (mid,gid) values (1,1)
insert into movie_genres (mid,gid) values (1,2)
```

Comment: The problem that I have is that I don't know how to insert data that is obtained from the datafile. The data that is inserted into movie and genre comes from the file. So it should be something similar to what I showed above, but I'm not sure how because mid should be obtained from the movie table while gid should be obtained from the genre table..

Comment: So I shouldn't insert the data myself, value by value

Comment: Ok so you need to create excel file by creating 2 columns homepage and its genre..then we can move forward..